# Add peg hole to each face of a model

Tags: faces, extrude

Is there a way to add a peg hole to each face of a model? There are a lot of faces, so it would be best if it could be done as one action (perhaps using a script).

Note that faces are not all aligned. They do all point towards the origin, though (meaning that the line between the origin and face's center is perpendicular).

Here's a picture of the model I want to add peg holes to using blender:

[image]

Comment: Could you add some image representing the issue? It will be better to understand what you mean.

Comment: @cgslav Okay, I added an image of the model, if that's what you mean. Note that I'm beginner, so there might be an obvious way to do this that I'm missing.

Comment: Do all the holes need to be the same size?

Comment: @Robin Betts Yes

Answer (score 2):

[image: final]

### Steps:

1. Select all **Faces**.
2. Press <kbd>I</kbd> twice to **Inset Individual Faces**.
3. Set size of **Inset** with your mouse or by entering value.
4. <kbd>X</kbd> > ***Faces*** to remove newly created ones.

   [image: gif]
5. (optional) You can add **Solidify** modifier.

Comment: The pegs are circular. Sorry I didn't mention that in the post.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exact enough for you ..  but ...

[image]

- <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> Inset all faces
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> Poke all faces
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel all new vertices
- <kbd>I</kbd> Inset new faces, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> 3 times for holding edges top and bottom of holes, and bottom face of holes.
- <kbd>I</kbd> for internal holding edge on bottom face of holes.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> on the keyboard to put on a couple of levels of subdivision.

The result of subdivision will be very slightly different diameter holes, though, depending on the number of sides in the faces. It may be more economical to tweak these than to adopt another possible approach, duplicating cutting curves to all faces.

Comment: Square faces would need further work, too...